# real time status update app in socket.io, unable to send status to database (mysql)

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, socket.io

I am working on status updating web app and using socket.io for this purpose but i am unable to send new status(message) database.
I am working on tutorial here is the link

[Real time status](https://codeforgeek.com/2015/03/real-time-app-socket-io/)

```
 var add_status = function (status,callback) {
    pool.getConnection(function(err,connection){
        if (err) {
          callback(false);
          return "error found";
        }
    connection.query("INSERT INTO status ('acstat') VALUES ('"+status+"')",function(err,rows){
            connection.release();
            if(!err) {
              callback(true);
            }
        });
     connection.on('error', function(err) {
              callback(false);
              return;
        });
    });
 }
```

Comment: "__i am unable to send new status(message) database__", what you mean by this? getting any error?

Comment: problem is that there is no error showing and data is not sending to database

Comment: add `console.log(err)` and  check in browser."
`if (err) {    console.log(err); callback(false);       return "error found";   }`